# How to access laravel env variables in node js?

Tags: node.js, laravel, env

I'm trying to access APP_KEY env variable of laravel in my socket.io server installation, but don't know how to access any of the laravel environment variables.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check this package for node.js [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

You can define path to `.env` file
as

`require('dotenv').config({path: '/custom/path/to/laravel/'});`

Comment: Thanks you so much, this was all I needed. :-)

Answer (score -3):

If they’re defined in the **.env** file then you can’t: it’s a PHP package Laravel uses that reads those values and makes them available in the application.

Instead, set *actual* environment variables on your server or in your host definition. Then both your Laravel application and any other application will be able to read them.