# Access Laravel .env file config in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, laravel, email

I am doing email code in NodeJS. I am trying to get configurations from Laravel .env file it's not going on. I am trying like this:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.ionos.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=my_email
MAIL_PASSWORD=my_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

And accesing it like this:

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: process.env.MAIL_HOST,
    port: process.env.MAIL_PORT,
    secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
        user: process.env.MAIL_USERNAME, // generated ethereal user
        pass: process.env.MAIL_PASSWORD // generated ethereal password
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you using Laravel Mix ?

Comment: No. I have a separate folder for all nodejs code.

Comment: Did you put the .env file in Nodejs root folder ? Have you given in require('dotenv').config() in the nodejs starter file ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access laravel env variables in node js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35483064/how-to-access-laravel-env-variables-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package to import your Laravel .env variables, somthing like

```
require('dotenv').config({path: '/path/to/laravel/env/file/vars.env'})
```

then you can use `process.env.MAIL_USERNAME` or `process.env.MAIL_PASSWORD`